# `ImportError` from python submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have the following structure for my Python modules:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aa.py
│   └── b
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── bb.py
└── root.py
```

#### Contents of aa.py

```
from b.bb import hello_bb

def hello_aa():
    hello_bb()
    print("hello from aa.py")
```

#### Contents of bb.py

```
def hello_bb():
    print("hello from bb.py")
```

#### Contents of root.py

```
from a.aa import hello_aa

hello_aa()
```

With Python 3.5.1, executing `python root.py` gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "root.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a.aa import hello_aa
  File ".../a/aa.py", line 1, in <module>
    from b.bb import hello_bb
ImportError: No module named 'b'
```

Both the `__init__.py` are empty.

Anything else I am missing to make this work?

Comment: from .b.bb imort hello_bb (a dot before the b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) inside a package (see [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports))

#### aa.py

```
from .b.bb import hello_bb
```

#### root.py

```
from .a.aa import hello_aa
```

Comment: I don't have to use relative import in `root.py`. Any ideas why it works there?

Comment: @armundle, I think it is because there is no `__init__.py` in the directory of `root.py`. BTW this directory should not be considered as a package because of this. You have module `root.py` and package `a` with submodule `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `aa.py` file you must import `hello_bb` like so:

```
from .b.bb import hello_bb

def hello_aa():
    hello_bb()
    print("hello from aa.py")
```